# Bash: Is it possible to reserve memory for a specific application

Tags: bash, memory, pipe, tesseract, imagemagick-convert

In one of my bash functions I use the following code to send ImageMagick's convert output thru a pipe to tesseract-ocr for conversion to text:

```
for a in ocr/*.tif*; do
  echo $a $(date +%T)
  for i in 2 4 8; do
    echo $a >> $i.txt
    convert $a -resize "$i"00% - | tesseract stdin q 2> /dev/null
    cat q.txt >> $i.txt
  done
  mv $a dun/
done
```

which works fine as long as I do nothing else at all while the function is running.

But any other use causes ImageMagick to generate temporary files instead which more than doubles the processing time for each input file. I assume this is because it objects to some new app's use of memory while convert is running. Is there any means in bash by which one can reserve a specific part of memory for one app's exclusive use?

Comment: I very much doubt that ImageMagick would behave differently (use more RAM or disk space) based on what else is running on the system. What evidence do you have that this is happening?

Comment: This is an operating system issue, not a programming problem.

Comment: Thomas, I quote: "...works fine as long as I do nothing else at all while the function is running.
But any other use causes ImageMagick to generate temporary files instead which more than doubles the processing time for each input file."

Comment: Bamar, you don't address the question asked either. I quote "Is there any means in bash by which one can reserve a specific part of memory for one app's exclusive use?"

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the command 'nice' is the tool for this problem. I posted the question after noticing that the processing time for this command

`convert $a -resize "$i"00% - | tesseract stdin q 2> /dev/null`

changed from about 1.5 minutes per input file with no other activity on the system, to about 3.3 minutes per input file when I was simultaneously taking multiple screenshots of my web browser.

So I changed the command to

`sudo nice -n -20 convert $a -resize "$i"00% - | tesseract stdin q 2> /dev/null`

for the latest batch and saw my average input file time go from about 1 minute to 1.25 minutes while again doing multiple screenshots of the browser.